# Can't open geoip.dat file. 'Failed to open stream' even though file exists

Tags: php, wordpress, geoip

I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting told a file doesn't exist, when it does.

I have a function in my wordpress theme like this:

```
function variable($value) {
$country_code = '';
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open(dirname(FILE)."GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
```

I've been trying different variations for geoip_open to get the code to see the file, but I'm receiving this on the front end:

> ( ! ) warning: fopen(.geoip.dat): failed to open stream: no such file or directory in c:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant\geoip.inc on line 314

That path it's giving, is absolutely correct.

I also tried to take out dirname(FILE) and just have the file name, but it shows the same error.

I did read another post on here about it, with the solution being given as it needs an absolute path, but how can I do this on a local machine, that will work the same when it's live? (At the moment it's in a WAMP environment)

UPDATE:
Here is my full function:

```
function variable($value) {
$country_code = '';
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open(dirname(__FILE__)."/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
switch ($value) {
    case 'prem_no':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $prem_no = '888-888-8888'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AU') { $prem_no = '1900 000 000'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'GB') { $prem_no = '0906 636 4355'; }
        else { $prem_no  = ''; }
        return $prem_no;
        break;


    case 'prem_rate':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $prem_rate = '$3.50'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $prem_rate = '$3.96'; } 
        else { $prem_rate  = '£1.53'; }
        return $prem_rate;
        break;

    case 'local_no':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $local_no = '755-555-5555'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $local_no = '1800 000 000'; } 
        else { $local_no  = '0207 111 6311'; }
        return $local_no;
        break;


    case 'sms_no':
        if($country_code == 'AUS') { $sms_no = '1977 1977'; } 
        else { $sms_no  = '78887'; }
        return $sms_no;
        break;

    case 'sms_rate':
        if($country_code == 'AUS') { $sms_rate = '25c'; } 
        else { $sms_rate  = '£1.50'; }
        return $sms_rate;
        break;

    case 'helpline':
        if($country_code == 'US') { $helpline = '700-777-7777'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $helpline = '1700 000 000'; }
        else { $helpline  = '0207 111 6210'; }
        return $helpline;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

The first case includes GB as a test (as I realised it was appearing correct for me as everything was going through 'else'). With the GB inserted, I get blanks again (along with the echo $country_code showing blank).

Comment: Use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) before `geoip_open`. And what is `FILE`? I assumed you wanted `__FILE__` like [this](http://php.net//manual/ro/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: Actually, using this `$gi = geoip_open("file://C:/wamp/www/clairvoyant/wp-content/themes/clairvoyant/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);` seems to load the entire page, and it looks like it loads. Is it just a case of re-wording it when it goes live?

Comment: `dirname(FILE)."GeoIP.dat" needs to be dirname(__FILE__)."/GeoIP.dat"`

Comment: Don't use `file://` protocol, not even `http`. Always use the full path of file on the drive.

Comment: Actually that doesn't seem to be loading the file, because although the rest of the page loads, when i echo $country_code I just get a blank space

Comment: @iautomation - Thanks, that clears the warning but there must be something else as my country_code is still outputting a blank

Comment: @LeeCollings According to your warning this is occurring inside `geoip.inc`. Also the file you are requesting above (`GeoIP.dat`) isn't the same as the one in the warning (`.geoip.dat`).

Comment: Yeah, the DAT file is referenced inside the INC file as $filename - that's what the error is referring to. The two files are the same file. The path has now fixed it (dirname(__FILE__)."/GeoIP.dat"

Comment: The GeoIP data is not 100% so you may have to try another IP address, though I doubt it. Try one of google's ip addresses: 74.125.225.82 Then try echoing the output of the country code variable directly.

Comment: @iautomation - can you add your comment as an answer and i'll mark it?

Comment: @iautomation - Using Google's IP in the function works fine, changes all the numbers to US style ones. Thanks alot!

Comment: Can a moderator or someone remove the downvote please on my post? I can't see at all how my question is unclear, or not showing research efforts. I'm now trying to remove my posting ban (Which is absolutely disgraceful) and can't do that without having negative votes removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirname(FILE)."GeoIP.dat"` needs to be `dirname(__FILE__)."/GeoIP.dat"`